# Dynamically wrap text in an anchor tag in Quilljs Error: addRange(): The given range isn't in document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I'm looking to search the editor text for any hashtags, and wrap the hashtag in an anchor tag to make it a link. So this: **`#whatsup`** would be this: **`<a href='http://help.com'>#whatsup</a>`**.

Here's what I have so far, which modifies the text correctly but results in this error. `addRange(): The given range isn't in document` And the cursor is removed, disallowing me to type anything else.

I get the same error when using `setContents` rather than `dangerouslyPasteHTML`

Just type any hashtag value such as #foo into the code snippet and look at your console to reproduce the error. Any help much appreciated.

```js
class RichEditor extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            editorHtml: '',
            hashTags: [] 
        }
        this.modules = {
            toolbar: [
                [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
                ['image', 'code-block']
              ]
        }

        this.editor = null;
        this.quillRef = null;
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange (html) {
        var blurtHashtags = this.editor.getText().match(/(?:^|\B)#[a-zA-Z][\w]{1,19}\b/g);

        if (blurtHashtags) {
            var modHtml = html.replace(blurtHashtags[0], "<a href='http://help.com'>" + blurtHashtags[0] + "</a>");
                 this.editor.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(modHtml);
        } else {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                editorHtml: html 
            }));
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        if (typeof this.quillRef.getEditor !== 'function') return;
        this.editor = this.quillRef.getEditor();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactQuill
                    ref={(el) => { this.quillRef = el; }} 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    modules={this.modules}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  RichEditor / > ,
  document.getElementById("quill")
);
```

```html
<div id="quill"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-quill@latest/dist/react-quill.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty interesting what is going on in the background. The solution what you find down there uses `setTimeout` with `0ms` delay to call `dangerouslyPasteHTML` function.

The reason behind why it is working now as expected that is technically not a good practice to modify the content in the handler event of the input field and by adding the delay the event loop will execute the input field modification - `dangerouslyPasteHTML` function - after the handler event.

The following code snippet resolves your issue, please take a look:

```js
class RichEditor extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            editorHtml: '',
            hashTags: [] 
        }
        this.modules = {
            toolbar: [
                [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
                ['image', 'code-block']
              ]
        }

        this.editor = null;
        this.quillRef = null;
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange (html) {
        const linkStart = `<a href="http://help.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">`;
        const linkEnd = `</a>`;

        // remove anchor tag around the hashtag value
        // in order to identify hashtag properly
        let modHtml = html.replace(linkStart, '');
        modHtml = modHtml.replace(linkEnd, '');
        const blurtHashtags = modHtml.match(/(?:^|\B)#[a-zA-Z][\w]{1,19}\b/g);

        if (blurtHashtags) {
            // rebuild link with anchor tag
            const link = `${linkStart}${blurtHashtags[0]}${linkEnd}`;
            modHtml = modHtml.replace(blurtHashtags[0], link);

            let editor = this.editor;
        
            setTimeout(() => {
                editor.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(modHtml);

                let selection = editor.getSelection();
                selection.index = modHtml.length;
                editor.setSelection(selection);
            }, 0);
        } else {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                editorHtml: html 
            }));
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        if (typeof this.quillRef.getEditor !== 'function') return;
        this.editor = this.quillRef.getEditor();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactQuill
                    className="quill-pre"
                    ref={(el) => { this.quillRef = el; }} 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    modules={this.modules}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  RichEditor / > ,
  document.getElementById("quill")
);
```

```css
.quill-pre p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="quill"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-quill@latest/dist/react-quill.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Obviously the rich text editor is not perfect at this point but fits for your requirements which was removing the error message what you had earlier. If you try typing the `test text value #wassup` then it won't throw any error message.

Additionally I have added `white-space: pre;` styling for the `p` tag in the component which resolves the white spacing issue after typing any hashtag.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This does remove the error message. However, it doesn't allow me to type anything after the hashtag. It essentially locks the cursor at the end of the hashtag link. I'll take a closer look and see if this can be improved on.

Comment: @silencedogood I have extended with the solution for the lock. Added `white-space: pre` for the included `p` tag in the `ReactQuill` component. Hope this helps!

Comment: Very cool! Well done, thanks. So using `setTimeout(..., 0)` will basically make your code run after the current event loop tick. I'm assuming, in this context, what's happening is some change handler  is inherently fired in quill.js, which it needs to complete prior to me setting content manually. This is a nebulous guess really.. I'm just trying to understand so this solution doesn't feel so arbitrary. Do you have an explanation for the `setTimeout`?

Comment: @silencedogood I have tried to explain in my answer, please find above. Hope that helps!